# How to conditionally include elements in xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

In xpath I have this

```
/isheet/data/item/column[@attributecolumnid='name']/displaydata/value
```

and using the ETL tool I have, I pass an index of which one to get from the result set. However this assumes that all `<displaydata>` elements has a `<value>`.

If I pass index 3, I expect it to get the displaydata/value from the third `<item>`. However some of the `<displaydata>` is like `<displaydata/>` and therefore has no `<value>` in it. This makes it get skipped in the xpath selector.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Conditional XPath expression are only possible with [XPath-2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/).

Comment: can i not just put an index selector on the item element?

Comment: You can - if that would satisfy your needs. Does it?

Comment: i think it did.